# $cordovaContacts loads very slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

I am trying to fetch contacts on android using $cordovaContacts,
when there is a 30-50 contacts it loads very fast, but if there is more then 200-250 contacts its very slow.
sometimes even 10-15 seconds.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the command line to produce your APK?

Comment: i do, why does it metter?

Comment: Your tag is wrong. This has nothing to do with *Phonegap-Build*. It is *Phonegap-CLI*. Changed your tag.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers) plugin might help you. It only searches for contacts with a phone number, which should make it load faster since on most phones a lot of contacts don't have phone numbers.